# I want a simple program to freeze/unfreeze input when I press a key

Tags: input, autohotkey, freeze

This seems like such a simple thing, yet I can't find it anywhere. I want a simple program (like AutoHotkey, but I can't find a way to do it with AutoHotkey) that will freeze my keyboard and mouse (whatever I'm pressing at the time keeps being pressed, even if I release the actual key/button) when I press a certain key, and keep it frozen until I press that key again (with the chosen key never being considered pressed by other programs).

I just want this so that if a game expects me to hold down some buttons, I can press the buttons, press the designated key, let go, then press the key again when I'm supposed to release the buttons.

Comment: I don't think this is really "such a simple thing". There are many different ways this could be accomplished, and the different ways would would work differently. Which way exactly you'll need for you game is also something to consider. Would need to know how your game processes input. If it were to be raw/direct input, it requires you to go for an even more advanced solution.

Comment: @0x464e Well, I made an AutoHotkey script that does pre-defined input, and that worked as expected. If there was a way to get AutoHotkey to do what I'm looking for, then it would work for the game I'm currently concerned about, and if it didn't work with something else later, I could worry about that then.

Answer (score 0):

This works in text editors. Not sure how it will work in games though.

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
#SingleInstance Force
#UseHook
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SendMode Input

Global isHold := false ; Alternates between "true" and "false" at each "LShift" press.

; Hotkey below will only be active if the game's window is active
#IfWinActive "PutYourGameWindowTitleHere"

; Sends {LShift Down} if isHold == false, {LShift Up} if isHold == true
; Asterisk means it will work even if other keys are held at the same time.
*LShift::Send % (isHold := !isHold) ? "{LShift Down}" : "{LShift Up}"

#IfWinActive
```

Update: Again, testing this in games you will have to do yourself.

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
#SingleInstance Force
#UseHook
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SendMode Input

Global aKeysToFreeze := { LShift: false, a: false }, isFreezeOn := false

`::fToggleFreeze()

^`:: ; You can use this to check the logical state of the key
If GetKeyState("a")
    msgbox Key is pressed.
else msgbox Key is not pressed.
return

fToggleFreeze() {
    Local
    Global aKeysToFreeze, isFreezeOn
    
    If isFreezeOn {                          ; If there are frozen keys,
        For sKeyName, isKeyFrozen in aKeysToFreeze {
            Send % "{" sKeyName " Up}"       ; send key up event for each key and
            aKeysToFreeze[sKeyName] := false ; set the each key's frozen state to false
        }
    } else {
        For sKeyName, isKeyFrozen in aKeysToFreeze
            If GetKeyState(sKeyName, "P")     ; If the key is physically pressed
                aKeysToFreeze[sKeyName] := true  ; set frozen state to true
    }
    isFreezeOn := !isFreezeOn    ; Frozen mode toggle
}

*a::Send {Blind}{a DownR}
*LShift:: Send {Blind}{LShift DownR}

#If !aKeysToFreeze["a"] ; If the key is frozen, the key up hotkey is blocked
*a Up::Send {Blind}{a Up}

#If !aKeysToFreeze["LShift"]
*LShift Up::Send {Blind}{LShift Up}
#If
```

Comment: So that would make it so that if I pressed left shift, it would stay pressed until I pressed left shift again, right? That's not quite what I was looking for. I guess I could kinda use this, but I'd have to add a line for every key I'd possibly want to have held, and I'd have to switch them between held and not held individually. I was looking for something that would make the other keys I was already holding when I pressed the specific designated key stay held until I pressed the designated key again, at which point all keys would stop being held (and without a ton of near-identical lines).

Comment: Agreeing with @0x464e, this does not seem to me a "simple thing". You will have to add code for each specific key. Looping through _every_ key every time and checking their state seems to me like a bad idea. If there is a better way to do what you want, I don't know it.